# Delineate watershed using manual points in RSAGA

Tags: r, saga, watershed

I'm currently trying for an automated solution to delineate watersheds within a large basin. I have a collection of locations (X,Y coords) for various tributaries reaching a larger river, and the end-game is to have each sub-basin delineated so I can calculate areas etc. I have been working in R, using SAGA and the RSAGA packages, (R 3.2.2, SAGA 2.1.2, OSX Yosemite 10.10.5).

So far, I have been able to fill the sinks:

```
rsaga.fill.sinks('dem_saga.sgrd', 'dem_sinkfilled.sgrd', method = "xxl.wang.liu.2006")
```

And have been able to make a raster of the same size and resolution as the dem, where all cells are 'NA' except for a single cell at the desired location to delineate the watershed (target.sgrd). This was achieved using `rasterize` command in R (e.g. `rasterize(target_point, dem, 1)`).

Unfortunately, although I am pretty sure the command I want is the '[Upslope Area](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_hydrology_4.html)' module, when it runs, I end up with a raster where every cell = 100.

I'm not sure exactly how to make a reproducible example, but my code:

```
rsaga.geoprocessor(lib = 'ta_hydrology', 4,
                    param = list(TARGET = 'target.sgrd',
                                 ELEVATION = 'dem_sinkfilled.sgrd',
                                 AREA = 'target_catch.sgrd',
                                 METHOD = 0))
```

Finally, the tutorial I have been working through is [here](http://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Exploring_Hydrological_Analyses_using_SAGA_GIS#Creating_a_Watershed_map). Jumping down to "Creating a Watershed map".